# How to subscribe to MS Graph calendar (not calendar event) change notifications, i.e new calendar created/deleted etc?

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

Microsoft Graph supports events change notifications, which are subscribed on the calendar level, so that we can get new/deleted/updated event notifications without constant polling. I got it to work fine with the .NET Graph SDK.

But what about the calendars themselves? Microsoft users are free to create/update/delete their own calendars. My app needs access to these calendars, but is it possible to get notifications for these as well instead of polling?

I can't find any documentation on this. Yet from my experience, the calendar apps/clients etc that support Microsoft accounts (including MS's own Outlook of course) seems to have no problem showing new calendars rather quickly. Are they likely using polling for this, or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Change notifications on calendars for instance the creation and deletion of calendars is not listed on the [MS Graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) as you rightly noted so I would go with the polling option. I would also suggest you add this as a feature request on the [MS Graph user voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) for consideration for future versions

Comment: Do you have any idea how some other calendar apps manage to sync up newly created/updated/deleted MS calendars super fast? For example, new calendars created in outlook.office.com shows up in desktop client instantly. I'm thinking since calendars are just Exchange mailbox folder items, could this have been done via some Exchange message notification? I only see those for messages, not folders though.

Comment: Please look into MAPI notifications, I think Outlook uses those. This would be a good starting point : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-notification-events